# float within 3 of each other if else statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

Is there a way in Java to make it so that if X is within 3 of Y that it will be true (need a if statement). 
I tried:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class e4 {
public static void main (String arg[])  {
    if ( ( (x - 3) <= y ) || ( (x - 3) <= y) || (x >= (y -3) ) || (x >= (y -3) ))
    {
    System.out.println("Your are within 3 of each other!");
    }
    else
        {
        System.out.println("Your NOT within 3 of each other."); 
        }  

        } //end main
        } //end class
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Have a look at `Math.abs`.

Comment: `(x - 3) <= y ) || ( (x - 3) <= y) ` What? `a||a` is `a`. Use `Math.abs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something simpler:

```
if (Math.abs(x - y) < 3.0) {
    // within 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was easier than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Math.abs`.  Do this.

```
if ( x >= y - 3 && x <= y + 3 )
```

Here's a case where `Math.abs` gives you a wrong answer, because the subtraction loses the small quantity from the small float.  If accuracy is important to you, you should avoid using `Math.abs` for this reason.

Note that it's possible to concoct an example where a similar thing happens with MY solution; but there are fewer such examples, and they only happen where the "ranges" represented by `x` and `y` contain parts that differ by more than 3 and parts that differ by less than 3.

```
    float x = - 0.2500001f;
    float y = 2.75f;
    System.out.println( x >= y - 3 && x <= y + 3 );   // Prints false (correct)
    System.out.println( Math.abs(x-y) <= 3.0);        // Prints true (wrong)
```

Comment: I would argue that `abs` is better.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: Well it's subjective of course, but I find the `abs` approach much easier to read and much more intelligible in terms of what it's trying to do. If you were to write this mathematically, you would never write something like this, you would instead say `|x - y| < 3`, which is what the `abs` approach exactly does. *Furthermore*, I dislike the fact that you have to write `3` twice.

Comment: Your argument comes down to "my opinion is better than your opinion".  I have mathematics textbooks that write this both ways.

Comment: If that's what you think, then I urge you to read my comment again. I have given valid reasons to prefer the `abs` approach, but of course it's opinion based at the end of the day.

Comment: Yes.  You wrote  "I find ...", then " ... you would never write ... " (demonstrably untrue), and lastly "I dislike ... ".  I'm not saying these reasons are invalid.  Simply that they're just your opinions, and mine differ.

Comment: Well your opinion is yours to keep; the most I can do is explain the rationale behind mine. Out of curiosity, then, do you prefer explicitly writing 3 a second time? I'm eager to know the justification behind that.

Comment: Math.abs() is easier but in this case i could understand why you would do this. thanks for the answer!

Comment: @arshaji - My edit contains my justification for preferring this solution.